# ERROR in ./ordenesPago.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-confirm-dialog' in '/resources/js/administracion'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I cloned a repo from git, and install all the dependences needed, but when runing npm run dev ai got this error for three files:

ERROR in ./resources/js/administracion/ordenesPago.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-confirm-dialog' in '/Users/davegomez/Desktop/Arco/arco/sistema-arco-v2.0/resources/js/administracion'
@ ./resources/js/administracion/ordenesPago.js 3:0-50 7:8-24 8:36-52
@ multi ./resources/js/administracion/ordenesPago.js

the strangest part is that I have already 'vue-confirm-dialog' installed:

This is my Package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress  --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-confirm-dialog": "^1.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@deveodk/vue-toastr": "^1.1.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
        "easy-circular-progress": "^1.0.4",
        "intro.js": "^2.9.3",
        "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
        "konva": "^8.2.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.8.1",
        "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
        "luxon": "^1.25.0",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.0",
        "sweet-modal-vue": "^2.0.0",
        "three": "^0.129.0",
        "v-calendar": "^2.1.5",
        "vue-3d-model": "^1.4.0",
        "vue-advanced-cropper": "^1.7.0",
        "vue-cal": "^3.9.1",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
        "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.14",
        "vue-easy-lightbox": "^0.16.1",
        "vue-introjs": "^1.3.2",
        "vue-konva": "^2.1.7",
        "vue-loading-overlay": "^3.4.2",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
        "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
        "vue-numeric": "^2.4.3",
        "vue-phone-number-input": "^1.1.10",
        "vue-trix": "^1.2.0",
        "vue-ui-preloader": "^1.2.1",
        "vue2-leaflet": "^2.7.1",
        "weekstart": "^1.0.1"
    }
}
```

and my package.mix.js

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
    .vue()
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/comprobante/modificar.js", "public/js/comprobante")
    .js("resources/js/pacientes/app.js", "public/js/pacientes")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/auth/login.js", "public/js/auth")
    .js("resources/js/comprobante/impresiones.js", "public/js/comprobante")
    .js("resources/js/comprobante/crear.js", "public/js/comprobante")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/doctores/dashboard.js", "public/js/doctores")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/seguros/pacientes.js", "public/js/seguros")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/comprobante/eliminados.js", "public/js/comprobante")
    .js("resources/js/pacientes/historial.js", "public/js/pacientes")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/caja/cierre.js", "public/js/caja")
    .js("resources/js/caja/cierreVue.js", "public/js/caja")
    .js("resources/js/comprobante/show.js", "public/js/comprobante")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/usuarios/index.js", "public/js/usuarios")
    .js("resources/js/seguros/estudios.js", "public/js/seguros")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/seguros/colaboradores.js", "public/js/seguros")
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/sucursales/ordenesRechazadas/listado.js",
        "public/js/sucursales/ordenesRechazadas"
    )
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/laboratorio/comisiones.js", "public/js/laboratorio")
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/laboratorio/asignaciones/procesos.js",
        "public/js/laboratorio/asignacion"
    )
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/doctores/listado.js", "public/js/doctores")
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/laboratorio/sucursales/pendientes.js",
        "public/js/laboratorio/sucursales"
    )
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/insumos/index.js", "public/js/insumos")
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/sucursales/comprobantesVentas.js",
        "public/js/sucursales/comprobantes"
    )
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/estudios/archivos/agregado.js",
        "public/js/estudios/archivos"
    )
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/estudios/archivos/previewModel3d.js",
        "public/js/estudios/archivos/preview"
    )
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/estudios/archivos/editorModel3d.js",
        "public/js/estudios/archivos/editor"
    )
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/informantes/cefalogramas.js",
        "public/js/informantes/estudios"
    )
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/chat/chat.js", "public/js/chat")
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/doctores/modificacion.js", "public/js/doctores")
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/doctores/pacientes/historial.js",
        "public/js/doctores/pacientes"
    )
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/sucursales/pedidoModificacion/listado.js",
        "public/js/sucursales/pedidoModificacion/listado.js"
    )
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/informantes/informes.js",
        "public/js/informantes/estudios"
    )
    .version()
    .js(
        "resources/js/administracion/ordenesPago.js",
        "public/js/administracion"
    )
    .version()
    .js("resources/js/timbrado/resource.js", "public/js/timbrado")
    .version()
    .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem since the new Version 1.1.0 came out 7 days ago. It just set back the version to 1.0.1 again and it worked. I dont know if there is something wrong with their new release.